# Best plugin for in-page image+text slider, Jquery Mobile + Phonegap app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, flexslider

I would like to insert a "slider" in my hybrid app.
I need each slide to contain an image and some text. And I would like it not to be a full page slider but a partly hidden in-page slider, like on the Amazon app:
[image]

Which is the best Jquery Mobile + Phonegap friendly slider ?
(I've heard of [Photoswipe](http://Photoswipe.com), [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/), [Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/), ...)

Thanks

Comment: if you dont want animation, you can create a horizontally scrollable div.

Comment: I don't want an ugly scroll bar, that's for sure. But you're right maybe this would be enough. Will horizontal scroll work well in Android, iOS and other platforms ?

Comment: iOS works, Android I dont know :)

Comment: yeah ok, then I'd rather get a plugin ;-)

Comment: test this fiddle on android http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6KhLb/

Comment: I am not sure how to test a jsfiddle on Android, but I just wen to this url with my android phone, and I can't scroll the images...

Comment: Then use a plugin, flexslider, swiper or create your own ;)

Comment: I just tried Flexslider : I can't swipe it on my phone http://jsfiddle.net/U5ySJ/. What is weird is that I can swipe their demo example here http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html but not with my own code.

Answer (score 2):

I chose Flexslider V2 and it seems to work fine : http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#result-page', function(){
    var suggestionSlider = $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        //slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 70,
        //itemMargin: 5,
        pausePlay: false,
        touch: true,
        //useCSS : false,
        pauseOnAction: true
    });
var slider = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider');
for (i = 0; i < matched.length; ++i) {
  slider.addSlide('<li><a class="suggestPro" proId="'+matched[i]['id']+'" href="#"><span><img src="images/boards/'+matched[i]['imageName']+'" /></span>'
                +'<p class="flex-caption">'+matched[i]['model']+'</p></a></li>'
                );

        }
        $('.flexslider').resize();

});
```

However V2.2 doesn't scroll well on Android phones (touch horizontal scroll), any hint would be apreciated.